# Fullcalendar plugin is displaying the events very thin "unreadable"

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I am using this wonderful [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) plugin to display events. I am also using css [bootstrap 3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

There is something weird is happening when displaying the event's title on the calendar. The height of the event box is very thin which makes it unreadable. I am not sure if there a conflict between the fullcalendar CSS classes and the bootstrap 3.2 package.

Here is a screenshot of the calendar 
[image]

How can I fix this issue and make the boxes readable?

This is the code that I am using to display/update the events

```
    $(function() {

        $('#users_menu').change( function(){

            var events = {
                url: 'ajax/getMyEvents.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    user_id: $(this).val()
                }
            }


            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', events);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', events);         
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
        });


        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            header: {
              right: 'prev,next today',
              center: 'title',
              left: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },      

            events: {
                url: 'ajax/getMyEvents.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    user_id: $('#users_menu').val()
                }
            },
            timeFormat: 'h:mm A',
            defaultView: 'agendaDay',
            eventDrop: function(event, delta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {

                if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) 
                    revertFunc();

                updateEvent(event, delta, minuteDelta, allDay, 'Drop', revertFunc); 
            },

            eventResize: function(event, delta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) {

                if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) 
                    revertFunc();

                updateEvent(event, delta, minuteDelta, false, 'endResize', revertFunc); 
            }


        });

    });

    function updateEvent(event, daysDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, eType, revertFunc)
    {
      //console.log(event);

      $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/updateEvents.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: ({
          id: event.id,
          min: minuteDelta,
          days: daysDelta,
          allday: allDay,
          eventType: eType
        }),
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
          if (!data)
          {
            revertFunc();
            return;
          }
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
        },
        error: function() {
          revertFunc();
        }
      });
    };


</script>
```

Thanks for your help and time in advance.

Comment: any custom or conflicting css?

Comment: nothing custom. but not sure if the CSS bootstrap have any conflicts.

Comment: try debugging by using 'inspect element' of your browser. then you can look at the CSS that is affecting it. ctrl - f on bootstrap.css, change it around.

Comment: any solution for this problem, i am facing the same issue. Need help.

Answer (score 0):

Solution Refered from [kriesi.at](http://www.kriesi.at/support/topic/wp-fullcalendar-plugin-displays-thin-vertical-line-again/)
[image: My Issue ScreenShot]
I faced same issues in fullcalendar plugin, which is over come by

```
a.fc-event {
min-height: 10px !important;
}
```

[image]